Cannot add a vertical line to the second X axis
I can add a horizontal line to the second Y axis, like this:
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": [5, 4, 7],
        "B": [200, 300, 100],
    },
    index=[1, 2, 3],
)

fig = px.bar(
    df["A"],
    orientation="v",
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=df.index,
        y=df["B"],
        yaxis="y2",
        name="B",
    )
)

fig.add_hline(
    y=df["B"].mean(),
    yref="y2",
)

fig.update_layout(
    xaxis_title=None,
    yaxis_title=None,
    legend_title=None,
    xaxis=dict(
        # autorange="reversed",
    ),
    yaxis=dict(
        side="left",
        showgrid=False,
    ),
    yaxis2=dict(
        overlaying="y",
        side="right",
        showgrid=False,
    ),
)

fig.show()


However, I cannot add a vertical line to the second X axis:
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": [5, 4, 7],
        "B": [200, 300, 100],
    },
    index=[1, 2, 3],
)

fig = px.bar(
    df["A"],
    orientation="h",
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        y=df.index,
        x=df["B"],
        xaxis="x2",
        name="B",
    )
)

fig.add_vline(
    x=df["B"].mean(),
    xref="x2",
)

fig.update_layout(
    xaxis_title=None,
    yaxis_title=None,
    legend_title=None,
    yaxis=dict(
        autorange="reversed",
    ),
    xaxis=dict(
        side="top",
        showgrid=False,
    ),
    xaxis2=dict(
        overlaying="x",
        side="bottom",
        showgrid=False,
    ),
)

fig.show()



I can achieve that with graph_objects.Bar instead of express.bar.
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": [5, 4, 7],
        "B": [200, 300, 100],
    },
    index=[1, 2, 3],
)

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(
        orientation="h",
        y=df.index,
        x=df["A"],
        name="A",
    )
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        y=df.index,
        x=df["B"],
        xaxis="x2",
        name="B",
    )
)

fig.add_vline(
    x=df["B"].mean(),
    xref="x2",
)

fig.update_layout(
    xaxis_title=None,
    yaxis_title=None,
    legend_title=None,
    yaxis=dict(
        autorange="reversed",
    ),
    xaxis=dict(
        side="top",
        showgrid=False,
    ),
    xaxis2=dict(
        overlaying="x",
        side="bottom",
        showgrid=False,
    ),
)

fig.show()


